# Flutter Autocomplete how to remove underline

Tags: flutter, dart

My autocomplete source code with some styling and self defined drop down because the drop down go beyond the screen because of the search icon added to the search bar:

[image]

This is almost like the top border of the drop down from the autocomplete. Anyway to remove this border?

```
  Container(
                  height:40.0,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10.0,right:10.0),
                  child: InputDecorator(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search, size: 25.0,),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                          width: 0,
                          style: BorderStyle.none,
                        ),
                      ),
                      filled: true,
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800]),
                      hintText: "Type in your text",
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      isDense: true,
                      // contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  ),
                    child: Autocomplete<String>(
                      optionsBuilder:
                          (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
                        if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
                          return const Iterable<String>.empty();
                        }
                        return _kOptions.where((String option) {
                          return option.contains(
                              textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
                        });
                      },
                      optionsViewBuilder: ((context, onSelected, options){
                        return Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                          child: Material(
                            elevation: 4.0,
                            child: ConstrainedBox(
                              constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200, maxWidth: 300), //RELEVANT CHANGE: added maxWidth
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: options.length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  final String option = _kOptions.elementAt(index);
                                  return InkWell(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      onSelected(option);
                                    },
                                    child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                      final bool highlight = AutocompleteHighlightedOption.of(context) == index;
                                      return Container(
                                        color: highlight ? Theme.of(context).focusColor : null,
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                        child: Text(option),
                                      );
                                    }),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: So, did u find any solution / workaround?

Comment: I ended up with a completely different design where the list is a page itself.  I think this is the right way for cross platform UI

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. This will create auto complete with rectangular border without underline.

```
Autocomplete<String>(
  fieldViewBuilder: (BuildContext context,
      TextEditingController fieldTextEditingController,
      FocusNode fieldFocusNode,
      VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted) {
    return TextFormField(
      cursorColor: Colors.white,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please enter item name';
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.white),
        ),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.white),
        ),
        labelText: "Enter Item Name",
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      controller: fieldTextEditingController,
      focusNode: fieldFocusNode,
    );
  },
  optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
    if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
      return const Iterable<String>.empty();
    }
    return ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"];
  },
  onSelected: (selectedValue) {},
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Container(
            height:40.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10.0,right:10.0),
            child: InputDecorator(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,//add this Disabling Underline/Border only when Enabled
focusedBorder: InputBorder.none, //Add this Removing the Underline/Border only when Focused
                border: InputBorder.none, //Add this when
                prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search, size: 25.0,),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                    width: 0,
                    style: BorderStyle.none,
                  ),
                ),
                filled: true,
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800]),
                hintText: "Type in your text",
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                isDense: true,
                // contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              ),
              child: Autocomplete<String>(
                optionsBuilder:
                    (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
                  if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
                    return const Iterable<String>.empty();
                  }
                  return _kOptions.where((String option) {
                    return option.contains(
                        textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
                  });
                },
                optionsViewBuilder: ((context, onSelected, options){
                  return Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Material(
                      elevation: 4.0,
                      child: ConstrainedBox(
                        constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200, maxWidth: 300), //RELEVANT CHANGE: added maxWidth
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: options.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            final String option = _kOptions.elementAt(index);
                            return InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                onSelected(option);
                              },
                              child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                final bool highlight = AutocompleteHighlightedOption.of(context) == index;
                                return Container(
                                  color: highlight ? Theme.of(context).focusColor : null,
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                  child: Text(option),
                                );
                              }),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: This make the autocomplete a rectangle shape and the underline of the drop down is still there

Comment: Only add those that are required. If you want to maintain the shape of you field do not include `border: InputBorder.none`